# Why does the (2, 3) map to the y value of a point instead of mapping 2 and 3 respectively to x and y value of that point? Common Lisp

Tags: mapping, common-lisp

I've been working on a jarvis march implementation for common lisp. The the jarvis march algorithm takes a bunch of points and returns the convex hull of that point cloud. I'm representing every point as a struct like this:

```
(defstruct point x y)
```

Then I went on to define a test set, but, since the notation to initialize a struct is rather long `(make-point :x 0 :y 1)`, I decided to make a function which automatically did this for me:

```
(defun make-points (list)
  (map 
    'list
    (lambda (e) (make-point :x (first e) :y (second e)))
    list))
```

Sadly enough it doesn't work.

```
(print (first (make-points '('(2 3)))))    ;prints out '#S(POINT :X QUOTE :Y (2 3))' => wrong
(print (make-point :x 2 :y 3))             ;prints out '#S(POINT :X 2 :Y 3)' => correct
```

It binds the complete list (2 3) to the y value of all things and it assigns nothing to the x value. Why does it do this and how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance, I'm fairly new to lisp (as you might have been able to guess from this question) and I would be highly appreciative if someone could help me out. If anyone knows any shortcuts or has any good arguments against my workmethod that would also be nice, although it might be better to tell me them in the comments since they would not be directly answering the question.

Comment: One quote is enough: `(make-points '((2 3)))`. Or better yet, `(make-points (list (list 2 3)))`.

Comment: The [DEFSTRUCT](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/m_defstr.htm) macro allows for some flexibility. If you find named arguments too heavy-weight in your case, you can define a BOA constructor

    `(defstruct (point (:constructor make-point (x y)))
      x y)`

Then you can call `(make-point 2 3)` and `(apply #'make-point '(2 3))`.

You can also have several constructors for a single struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CL-USER 1 > (defstruct point x y)
POINT

CL-USER 2 > (defun make-points (list)
              (map 
               'list
               (lambda (e) (make-point :x (first e) :y (second e)))
               list))
MAKE-POINTS
```

Tracing it:

```
CL-USER 3 > (trace make-points)
(MAKE-POINTS)

CL-USER 4 > (make-points '('(2 3)))
0 MAKE-POINTS > ...
  >> LIST : ((QUOTE (2 3)))
0 MAKE-POINTS < ...
  << VALUE-0 : (#S(POINT :X QUOTE :Y (2 3)))
(#S(POINT :X QUOTE :Y (2 3)))
```

Traditional print debug:

```
CL-USER 5 > (defun make-points (list)
              (map 
               'list
               (lambda (e)
                 (print (list :first (first e) :second (second e)))
                 (make-point :x (first e) :y (second e)))
               list))
MAKE-POINTS

CL-USER 6 > (untrace make-points)
(MAKE-POINTS)

CL-USER 7 > (make-points '('(2 3)))

(:FIRST QUOTE :SECOND (2 3)) 
(#S(POINT :X QUOTE :Y (2 3)))
```

Change the input. The list is already quoted. No need to quote it twice.

```
CL-USER 8 > (make-points '((2 3)))

(:FIRST 2 :SECOND 3) 
(#S(POINT :X 2 :Y 3))

CL-USER 9 >
```